# Second external display to be connected always has washed out colours

Tags: thunderbolt, displayport, color

I have a 14inch 2021 Macbook Pro M1 Max. I've attached 2 external displays (2x [LG Ultragear 27GP850](https://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-27gp850-b)) via the [anker thunderbolt 4 mini-dock](https://www.anker.com/products/a8398) connected with a thunderbolt 4 cable to my mac, and [USB C to displayport cables](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B09LCF2WQ3/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) from the dock.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the colours are dramatically different (worse) on the second monitor to be connected. To be very clear on that point: if I connect ***either*** monitor on its own, the colours are perfectly fine. Whichever monitor I connect second then has very washed out colours. In other words, this isn't a monitor calibration difference, because I can see the 'right' colours on both monitors if I connect them separately.

I have noticed that the second monitor I connect has different options (see below), so am wondering if the second monitor to be connected is being driven differently?

Any help/suggestions to get the colours to be more similar would be much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oh my god. I have exactly the same issue with the same monitors and the same computer. Did you ever fix it? I can just about endure the washed out looking second monitor after doing some colour profile changes but it still looks so much worse than the other one and I would love to be able to fix it. Been trying everything. Did you find a solution?

Comment: If you reduce both monitors to 60hz, which I believe is the max when you have 2 connected anyway, colours get a bit better...